# Nested form accepts_nested_attributes_for giving dynamic Array - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I am working on Rails4 with Nested form, accepts_nested_attributes_for i can able to generate the nested form but its giving dynamic array the the form when i inspect the form.

```
 <input type="text" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1403763304978][name]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1403763304978_name" class="form-control">
```

But it should be,

`<input type="text" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1][name]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1_name" class="form-control"`>

```
<div class="formWrapper">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1403764358820][name]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1403764358820_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1403764358820][telephone]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1403764358820_telephone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1403764358820][email]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1403764358820_email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][1403764358820][_destroy]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_1403764358820__destroy"><a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me out where i am missing the things...!!!

In first nested form set it's coming right,

```
<div class="formWrapper">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="AS" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][0][name]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_0_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" value="AS" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][0][telephone]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_0_telephone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
      <input type="text" value="AS" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][0][email]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_0_email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="false" name="event_venue[event_contact_details_attributes][0][_destroy]" id="event_venue_event_contact_details_attributes_0__destroy"><a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Event Venue Model,

```
has_many :event_contact_details, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_contact_details, allow_destroy: true
```

Controller,

```
def new
    @event_venue = EventVenue.new
    @event_venue.event_contact_details.build
  end
```

form,

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_contact_details do |builder| %>
            <%= render :partial => 'event_venues/event_contact_detail_fields', 
                       :locals => { :f => builder } %>
          <% end %>

          <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add More", f, :event_contact_details  %></p>
```

Comment: can you post your full form?

Comment: is this how your form looks like in your view file? and can you post your event_venue model and controller files?

Comment: I think its problem with child_index!!!

Comment: can you inspect what `@event_venue.event_contact_details.build` is building? ideally it should just initialise with nil values

Comment: yes, all values are nil, #<EventContactDetail id: nil, name: nil, telephone: nil, email: nil, event_id: nil, event_venue_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: you have somthing like `<% form_for @event_venue, url: your_path do |f| %>` for you form? We need to use the event_venue that we have initialised

Comment: Yes i have already added that!!!

Comment: After submitting the form it will take out all child forms and it will with first form.. And its not storing the child forms.... Thats my problem!!!

Comment: @RubyOnRails Can you paste the code snippet, which you are using for permit params. Also the params which you are getting by submitting the form.

Comment: Params are submitting... Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"siM04DtjyRYiSo97Ke0Cravg3pb7yVhm5Vaw4GjySnI=", "event_venue"=>{"name"=>"", "address"=>"", "country_id"=>"", "region_id"=>"", "city_id"=>"", "pincode"=>"", "event_contact_details_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"", "telephone"=>"", "email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Done"}
but not all array values are passing it's taking first array thats it..  i Did params.require(:event_venue).permit!

Comment: Try with `params.require(:event_venue).permit(:name,:address,:country_id,:region_id,:city_id,:pincode,event_contact_details_attributes: [:name,:email,:_destroy])`

Comment: Oh it's my fault it's because of my html- div and form wrappers, finally come to know...!!!! Oh its working now...